# SSH library for Java

Tags: java, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Does anyone have an example of an SSH library connection using Java.

Comment: I used to use Trilead SSH but when I checked the site today it seems they are giving up on it. :( It was my absolute favorite one.

Comment: BTW, it appears that Trilead SSH2 is being actively maintained (in Oct 2013): [https://github.com/jenkinsci/trilead-ssh2]

Comment: Trilead SSH2 has a fork at https://github.com/connectbot/sshlib

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The [Java Secure Channel (JSCH)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is a very popular library, used by maven, ant and eclipse. It is open source with a BSD style license.

Comment: You eed to download the source from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch/jsch-0.1.42.zip/download and run "ant javadoc"

Comment: I've tried using JSch some time ago and can not understand how it got so popular. It offers absolutely no documentation (not even within the source) and a horrible API design (http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/about-jsch-open-source-project/ sums it up quite well)

Comment: Yes Jsch is awful, this is better: https://github.com/shikhar/sshj

Comment: A variant of JSch with javadoc for the public methods: https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation

Comment: but jsch doesn't support dynamic socket forwarding:http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/62093-ssh-library-supports-dynamic-port-forwarding-anyone-knows-any.html

Comment: but any other client doesn't support `gssapi-with-mic` authentication :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/any-good-jsch-examples/11902536#11902536 contains an example for using JSCH to run commands and get the output.

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz How can we run commands such as "sqlplus / as sysdba" or "lsnrctl status"? They dont come with an output when i run these.

Comment: I'm having a bad experience trying to keep SFTP sessions alive. I don't know if others are better. BTW, Spring's SFTP API uses JSCH internally.

Comment: Here are some examples. But they are done in swing. http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

Comment: Here is usable API wrapper for JSch entrails http://stackoverflow.com/a/37067557/448078

Comment: User Spring SftpRemoteFileTemplate lib. it has the best API

Answer (score 69):

Update: The GSOC project and the code there isn't active, but this is:
https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj

hierynomus took over as maintainer since early 2015.  Here is the older, no longer maintained, Github link:

https://github.com/shikhar/sshj

---

There was a GSOC project:

http://code.google.com/p/commons-net-ssh/

Code quality seem to be better than JSch, which, while a complete and working implementation, lacks documentation. Project page spots an upcoming beta release, last commit to the repository was mid-august.

Compare the APIs:

http://code.google.com/p/commons-net-ssh/

```
    SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
    //ssh.useCompression(); 
    ssh.loadKnownHosts();
    ssh.connect("localhost");
    try {
        ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("user.name"));
        new SCPDownloadClient(ssh).copy("ten", "/tmp");
    } finally {
        ssh.disconnect();
    }
```

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

```
Session session = null;
Channel channel = null;

try {

JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();

// exec 'scp -f rfile' remotely
String command = "scp -f " + remoteFilename;
channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

// get I/O streams for remote scp
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

channel.connect();

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

// send '\0'
buf[0] = 0;
out.write(buf, 0, 1);
out.flush();

while (true) {
    int c = checkAck(in);
    if (c != 'C') {
        break;
    }

    // read '0644 '
    in.read(buf, 0, 5);

    long filesize = 0L;
    while (true) {
        if (in.read(buf, 0, 1) < 0) {
            // error
            break;
        }
        if (buf[0] == ' ') {
            break;
        }
        filesize = filesize * 10L + (long) (buf[0] - '0');
    }

    String file = null;
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        in.read(buf, i, 1);
        if (buf[i] == (byte) 0x0a) {
            file = new String(buf, 0, i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // send '\0'
    buf[0] = 0;
    out.write(buf, 0, 1);
    out.flush();

    // read a content of lfile
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    fos = new FileOutputStream(localFilename);
    int foo;
    while (true) {
        if (buf.length < filesize) {
            foo = buf.length;
        } else {
            foo = (int) filesize;
        }
        foo = in.read(buf, 0, foo);
        if (foo < 0) {
            // error
            break;
        }
        fos.write(buf, 0, foo);
        filesize -= foo;
        if (filesize == 0L) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fos.close();
    fos = null;

    if (checkAck(in) != 0) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // send '\0'
    buf[0] = 0;
    out.write(buf, 0, 1);
    out.flush();

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}

} catch (JSchException jsche) {
    System.err.println(jsche.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.err.println(ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
} finally {
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used Apache SSHD code (which offers an async API) as seed which gave the project a kickstart.

Comment: Great. I started a project using JSch, but I really like to switch, if I hear more positive feedback about commons-net-ssh.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was the GSOC student :)

Comment: happy to announce http://github.com/shikhar/sshj - you can find jar's there, figuring out how to get it on a maven repo

Comment: jsch's SFTP is much simpler than what's given here. Perhaps this is old code, but it certainly isn't an example of the modern API.

Comment: Also -- to the best of my knowledge, jsch is the _ONLY_ SSH implementation for Java with any kind of SSH agent support available.

Answer (score 28):

I just discovered [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/), which seems to have a much more concise API than JSCH (but it requires Java 6).  The documentation is mostly by examples-in-the-repo at this point, and usually that's enough for me to look elsewhere, but it seems good enough for me to give it a shot on a project I just started.

Comment: SSHJ is actually workable by someone from the outside world. JSCH is a mess of bad documentation and API design with hidden and largely indecipherable dependencies. Unless you want to spend a lot of time walking through code to try to figure out what's up, use SSHJ.

(And I wish I was being harsh or facetious about JSCH. I really do.)

Comment: Yes, sshj. Everything I tried with it worked: SCP, remote process execution, local and remote port forwarding, agent proxy with [jsch-agent-proxy](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch-agent-proxy). JSCH was a mess.

Comment: The problem with SSHJ is that it's very hard to execute multiple commands. SSHJ may be great for fire-and-forget of commands, but it's a pain if you want to program more complicated interaction. (I just wasted half a day on it)

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at the very recently released [SSHD](http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/), which is based on the Apache MINA project.

Comment: Using it, however there is lacking of documentation and examples.

Comment: Looks like a lack of documentation is putting it lightly :/

Answer (score 5):

There is a brand new version of Jsch up on github: https://github.com/vngx/vngx-jsch Some of the improvements include: comprehensive javadoc, enhanced performance, improved exception handling, and better RFC spec adherence. If you wish to contribute in any way please open an issue or send a pull request.

Comment: Too bad there hasn't been a new commit in over 3 years now.

Comment: @Scott Where can I find examples to start working with? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I took miku's answer and jsch example code. I then had to **download multiple files** during the session and **preserve original timestamps**. This is my example code how to do it, probably many people find it usefull. Please ignore filenameHack() function its my own usecase.

```
package examples;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ScpFrom2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,String> params = parseParams(args);
        if (params.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("usage: java ScpFrom2 "
                    + " user=myid password=mypwd"
                    + " host=myhost.com port=22"
                    + " encoding=<ISO-8859-1,UTF-8,...>"
                    + " \"remotefile1=/some/file.png\""
                    + " \"localfile1=file.png\""
                    + " \"remotefile2=/other/file.txt\""
                    + " \"localfile2=file.txt\""

            );
            return;
        }

        // default values
        if (params.get("port") == null)
            params.put("port", "22");
        if (params.get("encoding") == null)
            params.put("encoding", "ISO-8859-1"); //"UTF-8"

        Session session = null;
        try {
            JSch jsch=new JSch();
            session=jsch.getSession(
                    params.get("user"),  // myuserid
                    params.get("host"),  // my.server.com
                    Integer.parseInt(params.get("port")) // 22
            );
            session.setPassword( params.get("password") );
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); // do not prompt for server signature

            session.connect();

            // this is exec command and string reply encoding
            String encoding = params.get("encoding");

            int fileIdx=0;
            while(true) {
                fileIdx++;

                String remoteFile = params.get("remotefile"+fileIdx);
                String localFile = params.get("localfile"+fileIdx);
                if (remoteFile == null || remoteFile.equals("")
                        || localFile == null || localFile.equals("") )
                    break;

                remoteFile = filenameHack(remoteFile);
                localFile  = filenameHack(localFile);

                try {
                    downloadFile(session, remoteFile, localFile, encoding);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{ session.disconnect(); } catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    private static void downloadFile(Session session, 
            String remoteFile, String localFile, String encoding) throws Exception {
        // send exec command: scp -p -f "/some/file.png"
        // -p = read file timestamps
        // -f = From remote to local
        String command = String.format("scp -p -f \"%s\"", remoteFile); 
        System.console().printf("send command: %s%n", command);
        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command.getBytes(encoding));

        // get I/O streams for remote scp
        byte[] buf=new byte[32*1024];
        OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        buf[0]=0; out.write(buf, 0, 1); out.flush(); // send '\0'

        // reply: T<mtime> 0 <atime> 0\n
        // times are in seconds, since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC 
        int c=checkAck(in);
        if(c!='T')
            throw new IOException("Invalid timestamp reply from server");

        long tsModified = -1; // millis
        for(int idx=0; ; idx++){
            in.read(buf, idx, 1);
            if(tsModified < 0 && buf[idx]==' ') {
                tsModified = Long.parseLong(new String(buf, 0, idx))*1000;
            } else if(buf[idx]=='\n') {
                break;
            }
        }

        buf[0]=0; out.write(buf, 0, 1); out.flush(); // send '\0'

        // reply: C0644 <binary length> <filename>\n
        // length is given as a text "621873" bytes
        c=checkAck(in);
        if(c!='C')
            throw new IOException("Invalid filename reply from server");

        in.read(buf, 0, 5); // read '0644 ' bytes

        long filesize=-1;
        for(int idx=0; ; idx++){
            in.read(buf, idx, 1);
            if(buf[idx]==' ') {
                filesize = Long.parseLong(new String(buf, 0, idx));
                break;
            }
        }

        // read remote filename
        String origFilename=null;
        for(int idx=0; ; idx++){
            in.read(buf, idx, 1);
            if(buf[idx]=='\n') {
                origFilename=new String(buf, 0, idx, encoding); // UTF-8, ISO-8859-1
                break;
            }
        }

        System.console().printf("size=%d, modified=%d, filename=%s%n"
                , filesize, tsModified, origFilename);

        buf[0]=0; out.write(buf, 0, 1); out.flush(); // send '\0'

        // read binary data, write to local file
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(localFile);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            while(filesize > 0) {
                int read = Math.min(buf.length, (int)filesize);
                read=in.read(buf, 0, read);
                if(read < 0)
                    throw new IOException("Reading data failed");

                fos.write(buf, 0, read);
                filesize -= read;
            }
            fos.close(); // we must close file before updating timestamp
            fos = null;
            if (tsModified > 0)
                file.setLastModified(tsModified);               
        } finally {
            try{ if (fos!=null) fos.close(); } catch(Exception ex){}
        }

        if(checkAck(in) != 0)
            return;

        buf[0]=0; out.write(buf, 0, 1); out.flush(); // send '\0'
        System.out.println("Binary data read");     
    }

    private static int checkAck(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        // b may be 0 for success
        //          1 for error,
        //          2 for fatal error,
        //          -1
        int b=in.read();
        if(b==0) return b;
        else if(b==-1) return b;
        if(b==1 || b==2) {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            int c;
            do {
                c=in.read();
                sb.append((char)c);
            } while(c!='\n');
            throw new IOException(sb.toString());
        }
        return b;
    }


    /**
     * Parse key=value pairs to hashmap.
     * @param args
     * @return
     */
    private static Map<String,String> parseParams(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String keyval : args) {
            int idx = keyval.indexOf('=');
            params.put(
                    keyval.substring(0, idx),
                    keyval.substring(idx+1)
            );
        }
        return params;
    }

    private static String filenameHack(String filename) {
        // It's difficult reliably pass unicode input parameters 
        // from Java dos command line.
        // This dirty hack is my very own test use case. 
        if (filename.contains("${filename1}"))
            filename = filename.replace("${filename1}", "Korilla ABC ÅÄÖ.txt");
        else if (filename.contains("${filename2}"))
            filename = filename.replace("${filename2}", "test2 ABC ÅÄÖ.txt");           
        return filename;
    }

}
```

Comment: Were you able to reuse a session and avoid the overhead of connecting/disconnecting?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/, Compile src\com\trilead\ssh2 on windows linux or android , it can create Local Port Forwarder or create Dynamic Port Forwarder or other else