# Simple SSH Tunnel in Java

Tags: java, ssh, tunnel

I want to create an SSH Tunnel in Java.  I noticed quite a few Java SSH libraries on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java).  Before I dig into each option, maybe someone can give me some code snippets of how they did it or at least tell me which client library would work best.

I only need tunneling.  I won't need stuff like file transfers, terminal emulation, etc.  Is there a simple few lines of code that can forward a port on the server to work on my client's localhost adapter?  Ideally both client and server would be in Java, but I'll settle for just client for now.

Comment: NB: This question was also informative on this subject matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954454/fast-implementation-of-a-port-forward-in-java

Comment: here is an example I put together on another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16023513/311525

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, as pointed out in the other question, [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is indeed a great choice and has several examples [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/). The [PortForwardingL.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java) class might be a good starting point.

Comment: I like the BSD license on this library.  Thank you for pointing me directly to the sample I needed to see!

Answer (score 22):

You can do this with several libraries. My favorite is the ssh library inside MindTerm package,

http://linuxmafia.com/pub/java/ISNetworks-MindTerm-1.2.1-SCP3.tar.gz

You can open a tunneled connection like this,

```
  SSHSocketFactory fact = new SSHSocketFactory(sshHost, sshPort, new SSHPasswordAuthenticator(sshUser, sshPassword));

  sock = fact.createSocket(host, port);
```

Comment: +1 Wow.  This is very simple.  Too bad the license is kind of strange (my bad for not mentioning I need something BSD-like).  I tried to accept this also as an answer, but SO only allows one answer.  I at least upvoted your answer.  Thanks for your help.