# SSH port fowarding with SSHj

Tags: java, ssh, port, forwarding, sshj

I am trying to create a tunnel to use a service behind a firewall, that supports SSH. I wanted a complete solution in java, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I found this [github snip](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/examples/RemotePF.java) and based on that I created the following code to keep a background thread giving me the tunnel:

```
// property on surrounding class
// static final SSHClient sshclient = new SSHClient();

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String host = "10.0.3.96";
            sshclient.useCompression();
            sshclient.addHostKeyVerifier("30:68:2a:20:21:9f:c8:e8:ac:b4:a7:fc:2d:a7:d0:26");
            sshclient.connect(host);
            sshclient.authPassword("messy", "messy");
            if (!sshclient.isAuthenticated()) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to authenticate against '%s'", host));
            }
            Forward forward = new Forward(8111);
            InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80);
            SocketForwardingConnectListener listener = new SocketForwardingConnectListener(addr);

            sshclient.getRemotePortForwarder().bind(forward, listener);
            sshclient.getTransport().setHeartbeatInterval(30);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:8111").openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            sshclient.getTransport().join();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (sshclient != null && sshclient.isConnected()) {
                sshclient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

The problem is that if I connect to a remote SSH server like '10.0.3.96' it does not work. If I use the local SSH server on my localhost it will work. I have been going thru different configurations with any luck and tried debugging, but I cannot grasp what is going on inside the SSHj package.

Now it does not have to be a SSHj solution, but that would be preferred since other parts of the code are fully implemented and using SSHj and I do not want to mix two SSH packages in one project.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Define 'does not work'. What happens instead?

Comment: When it is not working the HttpConnection I am testing with throws an exception saying the Connection is refused. When is it working, I get printed what google.com serves up of contents.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this.  It takes in a list of servers to connect to.  It will tunnel each intermediate connection to the last server.  I have not tested with more than 2 servers, but it should work.  This answer was adapted from the overthere project and written in groovy.  You should only need imports to get it working in groovyconsole.

```
@Grab(group='net.schmizz', module='sshj', version='0.8.1')
@Grab(group='org.bouncycastle', module='bcprov-jdk16', version='1.46')

//the sequence of hosts that the connections will be made through
def hosts = ["server1", "server2"]
//the starting port for local port forwarding
def startPort = 2222
//username for connecting to all servers
def username = 'user'
def pw = 'pass'

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//

final TunnelPortManager PORT_MANAGER = new TunnelPortManager()

//list of all active port forwarders
List<PortForwarder> portForwarders = []

Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

/**
 *  Established the actual port forwarder 
 */
class PortForwarder extends Thread implements Closeable {
    private final SSHClient sshClient;
    private final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress;
    private final ServerSocket localSocket;
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public PortForwarder(SSHClient sshClient, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, ServerSocket localSocket) {
        this.sshClient = sshClient;
        this.remoteAddress = remoteAddress;
        this.localSocket = localSocket;
    }

    private static String buildName(InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, Integer localPort) {
        return "SSH local port forward thread [${localPort}:${remoteAddress.toString()}]"
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LocalPortForwarder.Parameters params = new LocalPortForwarder.Parameters("127.0.0.1", localSocket.getLocalPort(),
                remoteAddress.getHostName(), remoteAddress.getPort());
        LocalPortForwarder forwarder = sshClient.newLocalPortForwarder(params, localSocket);
        try {
            latch.countDown();
            forwarder.listen();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {/* OK. */}
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        localSocket.close();
        try {
            this.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {/* OK.*/}
    }
}

/**
 *  Will hand out local ports available for port forwarding
 */
class TunnelPortManager {
    final int MAX_PORT = 65536

    Set<Integer> portsHandedOut = new HashSet()

    ServerSocket leaseNewPort(Integer startFrom) {
        for (int port = startFrom; port < MAX_PORT; port++) {
            if (isLeased(port)) {
                continue;
            }

            ServerSocket socket = tryBind(port);
            if (socket != null) {
                portsHandedOut.add(port);
                println "handing out port ${port} for local binding"
                return socket;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a single free port in the range [${startFrom}-${MAX_PORT}]...");
    }

    synchronized void returnPort(ServerSocket socket) {
        portsHandedOut.remove(socket.getLocalPort());
    }

    private boolean isLeased(int port) {
        return portsHandedOut.contains(port);
    }

    protected ServerSocket tryBind(int localPort) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
            ss.setReuseAddress(true);
            ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", localPort));
            return ss;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}


PortForwarder startForwarder(PortForwarder forwarderThread) {
    forwarderThread.start();
    try {
        forwarderThread.latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return forwarderThread;
}


SSHClient getSSHClient(username, pw, String hostname, int port=22){
    SSHClient client = new SSHClient()
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier())
    client.connect(hostname, port)
    client.authPassword(username, pw)
    return client
}

int hostCount = hosts.size()
String hostname = hosts[0]

SSHClient client = getSSHClient(username, pw, hostname)
println "making initial connection to ${hostname}"

Session session

//create port forwards up until the final
for (int i=1; i<hostCount; i++){
    hostname = hosts[i]
    println "creating connection to ${hostname}"
    ServerSocket ss = PORT_MANAGER.leaseNewPort(startPort)
    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(hostname, 22)

    PortForwarder forwarderThread = new PortForwarder(client, remoteAddress, ss)
    forwarderThread = startForwarder(forwarderThread)
    session = client.startSession()

    println "adding port forward from local port ${ss.getLocalPort()} to ${remoteAddress.toString()}"
    portForwarders.add(forwarderThread)

    client = getSSHClient(username, pw, "127.0.0.1", ss.getLocalPort())
}

session = client.startSession()

//shut down the running jboss using the script
Command cmd = session.exec("hostname")
String response = IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString()
cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
println "response -> ${response}"

portForwarders.each { pf ->
    pf.close()
}

session.close()
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: I have looked over the code and it seems sound. However I have changed jobs and no longer have access to the project where this was needed. Also I am not too big on groovy so I may need someone to verify this works before I can accept this answer.

Comment: groovy is pretty much java+.  You can run java right inline.  Download groovy, add to path, type groovyconsole, paste code, add imports, run.