# How to use sshj to tunnel through an intermediate server without using local port forward

Tags: sshj

I am trying to use [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj) to tunnel through an gateway (jump point) server:

A -> B -> C

The caveat is that I need to do this without setting up a [local port forward](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/examples/LocalPF.java).  I need to make a direct connection to server B, then make another ssh connection to server C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution that didn't utilize local port forwarding.  A potential non port forward solution could be to get a PTY from the first connection, then just execute ssh; but, in initial testing the new session did not seem to transfer over for me.

The best solution I found for this tunneling requirement was found in a piece of code [here](https://github.com/xebialabs/overthere/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xebialabs/overthere/ssh/SshTunnelConnection.java) in the overthere project.

UPDATE:  I answered a similar question with some code here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023513/311525