# Security / TLS support of Compose for Redis on IBM Bluemix Public?

Tags: redis, ibm-cloud, compose-db

I am thinking about using `Compose for Redis` on Bluemix Public but...

1. In Bluemix catalog, there is the sentence: `Compose's platform gives you a configuration pre-tuned for high availability and locked down with additional security features.` - does anobody know what does `additional security features` mean?
2. I've tried to test TLS support and it seems that the service doesn't support it. Am I right?
3. Is there any best scenario how to protect transmissions from my app to `Compose for Redis` service on Bluemix Public (my app is running as Cloud Foundry app)?
4. Are there any alternatives with TLS support enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) See the following links for some more information.

- https://www.compose.com/databases/redis
- https://help.compose.com

(2) This is currently not supported but I believe it is being worked on.  Please contact me offline and share your timescales to understand if this is viable.

(3) Not that I'm aware of.

(4) Not that I'm aware of.

---

Update:

TLS is now available - https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/02/ibm-cloud-compose-redis-available-tls-encryption/.

Thanks for pointing this out, [zdenek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5195758/zden%c4%9bk)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I've found out that there is a possibility of using a SSH portal + IP whitelisting on Compose. Unfortunately, there is no such option on IBM Bluemix :-/ so it seems this service is unusable.

Comment: It may be possible to open the ssh session programmatically from your cf app using a ssh library, but if you do that I'm not sure if ssh portals are available on Bluemix.  If you think programmatic ssh may work for you, I can find out about portal support on Bluemix (e.g. manually setup via support ticket).  Redis+TLS is being worked on, but that depends on how long you are able to wait.

Comment: Java ssh tunnel example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677248/simple-ssh-tunnel-in-java

Comment: Thanks. I'll try ssh tunneling via cf app (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html) - will see if works. Redis+TLS would be the best solution, of course. Our deadline isn't strict yet (we will develop the app one more month or two).