# Run du -f linux command and get the result in java

Tags: java, linux, runtime.exec

I have a scenario like this:

I need to connect to a remote server(linux) and execute du -h command to find the disk usage of a particular folder (say /home/oracle/TEST). So, i need to find the disk usage of TEST folder. and print the result in java. How can i do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = null; 

                try { 

                // run the Unix "ps -ef" command 
                    Socket s1=new Socket("10.1.7.237",1521);
                    System.out.println(s1.isConnected());
                    System.out.println(s1.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    System.out.println("connected");
                    System.out.println();

                     PrintWriter wr=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s1.getOutputStream()),true);  
                     wr.println("Hi Server...");  
                     wr.flush();  
                     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream()));   
                     System.out.println(br.readLine());   
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("du -h");

                    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 

                    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream())); 

                // read the output from the command 

                    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n"); 
                    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) { 
                        System.out.println(s); 
                    } 
                    // read any errors from the attempted command 

                    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n"); 
                    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) { 
                        System.out.println(s); 
                    } 

                    System.exit(0); 
                } 
                catch (IOException e) { 
                    System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: "); 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(-1); 
            } 
            }
```

I have tried this also but got this exception:

```
    Cannot run program "du": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "du": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at testprog.main(testprog.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: I have detected the error :If i replace the du -h  command with tasklist the the program works fine.The issue is Rumtime.getRuntime.exec() executes the command in the current runtime (as i am doing in windows) but i want to run the command in linux server and not in windows.

Comment: That will not give you the result you are looking for. You want to execute your command on the remote machine. Using `tasklist` gives you the result of your windows box, not your remote linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you are actually executing the du -h command on the remote server.
Runtime.getRuntime() gets the Runtime instance on the local host.
You should use a library that can telnet to the remote host and execute the command there, like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

You can see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html
that this RunTime is getting the host envairorment and exec "du -h" at host computer and not on remote server

Answer (score 0):

When executing a command in Java, you're not in a classic shell. Hence you don't have access to the same environnement variables, built-in commands, etc.
Try with `/usr/bin/du`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("du -h");` directly to execute something on a remote machine. The command is executed on the machine where the java programm has been started.

[How do I run SSH commands on remote system using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514439/how-to-run-ssh-commands-on-remote-system-through-java-program) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh ${hostname-goes-here} du -h /path/to/folder");
```

Of course, you will need to have `ssh` available on your path on the client's side and in order for the above command to work, you will need to have added your public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.