# How can I call Shell Script on remote machine from Browser or Azure Functions

Tags: linux, shell, azure, azure-functions

I have a shell file on the remote machine which will perform certain required actions. Can I call this shell from outside of the VM.

Like by using Azure functions or browser itself.

Here is the Snapshot for shell.

[image]

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

According your needs,I suggest you connecting to a remote server using `SSH` and execute commands.

I'm not sure which language you are using. So,I just offer `java` sample code for you here.

You could use `SSH` component `JCraft` for remote connection and shell commands invocations.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

String command = "/tmp/myscript.sh";
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.connect();

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();

byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
  while (in.available() > 0) {
      int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
      if (i < 0) {
          break;
      }
      System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if (channel.isClosed()) {
      if (channel.getExitStatus() == 0) {
          System.out.println("Command executed successully.");
      }
      break;
  }
}
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Also,you could refer to this thread [How do I run SSH commands on remote system using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514439/how-do-i-run-ssh-commands-on-remote-system-using-java).

Hope it helps you. Any concern,please feel free to let me kown.