# Running shell command though jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, bash, shell, jdbc

Is it possible to run linux shell commands though jdbc in java code and how?
I have been trying this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + this.host + "/" + this.db + "?", properties);
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        String sql = "\\! touch /home/dbsms/testfile";
        statement.execute(sql);
```

but I'm getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" error. The reason why I am trying this:
MySQL server is running on a machine which is on a protected (no internet) network. My java application is designed to manipulate DB. It is a document management DB. So once a new document is inserted into DB I need to notify users. There is another machine on the same network which is able to send SMS. What I need to to is create a file that contains a text of an SMS and is named as a phone number, and the deamon on SMS machine will pick it up and process. I know that there are libs that would let me execute shell command on a remote computer via ssh, but I would like to use jdbc if possible.

Comment: With jdbc, we are having a database connection, and this we must give a valid sql statement to execute.

Comment: No idea about executing shell script running from sql. But I can help you execute the same from java code.

Comment: so no "\! command" is possible then?

Comment: that would be great @Abhijit Pritam Dutta

Comment: It would be much cleaner if you would use sftp/scp in your java application and put your text file to the database host, than trying to execute bash script there.

Comment: @AndrijaPetrovic, I have provided a solution in java.

Comment: I doubt it.Perhaps with a stored proc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run SSH commands on remote system using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514439/how-do-i-run-ssh-commands-on-remote-system-using-java)

Comment: It would be a serious security problem indeed if anyone with access to the database could run shell commands on the database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, JDBC is for executing SQL statements in a database.

Java can run OS level commands but they are limited to the box where the JVM is running.

It sounds to me (I can be wrong) that you want to run them in the server, not your local machine. If this is the case then you would need to open a remote connection to the server, probably using SSH or similar in order to run your command remotely.

Answer (score 0):

With jdbc, we are having a database connection, and this we must give a valid sql statement to execute. So you are getting above error.

But, with java you can execute shell commands. [This article](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/) will help you.

Comment: hmm yes that is true. However I need to create a file on a remote machine not a local one. But thank you anyway

Comment: then, ChannelSftp(https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) would help you.

Comment: @AndrijaPetrovic then, you can use JSch library(http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). Or, as I've mentions use ssh command with Runtime.exec("ssh ....") and then use it to execute commands you need