# How to write interactive SSH command call in java

Tags: java, ssh, runtime

I have a ssh command like this

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=1 -L 27106:name.com:27222 user@differentname.com
```

when i enter this it ask for some condition like yes/no : yes
then ask for password :

i want to make this work through Java

i have implemented with Runtime but structing at yes or no, its not going to further

below is my code

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=1 -L 27106:name.com:27222 user@differentname.com");
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while (in.ready()) {
  String s = in.readLine();
  System.out.println(s);
}
System.out.println("exit");

p.waitFor();
```

any one please help me on achieving this.
I have looked Jsch library didn't get it.
please help me on this.
I really appreciate it.

Comment: Refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514439/how-do-i-run-ssh-commands-on-remote-system-using-java

Comment: yeah i have gone through it. can't it possible to set expected values in java code(using RunTime) itself without specifying in .ssh/config?

Comment: @Amitkumar pls any help?

Comment: Not sure if Java supports that natively, you can use some library ( http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ )