# Jsch - Sending commands via ssh

Tags: java, ssh, infinite-loop, freeze, jsch

The problem: I cant seem to get out of the "infinite loop/block" from the buffered reader.readline(). It passes it once and then just hangs there after the second come around from the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
public void sendCommand(String command){
        {
            String line;
             try{
                 while((line = consoleOutput.readLine())!= null)
                    {
                         System.out.println(line);
                         if(line.equals("rkscli:") || line.equals("password :") || line.equals("Please login: ")){
                             pin.write((command + "\n\r").getBytes());
                         }
                    }
                 }
```

I am using the method used by nilbot from: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194439/sending-commands-to-server-via-jsch-shell-channel)
I am doing exactly this, where I am trying to send commands via a shell.

The Problem:

What I am trying to accomplish is getting the program to wait until the server is ready to receive more commands (wait for the prompt "rkscli", because some commands take more time). What can I do to accomplish this? I am currently using the pipedinput/output method.

Other info:

The server will give me ""'s (empty strings with newlines) before the prompt. After a few of those it will give me prompt. I also noticed that if I changed the code so that it looked like this:

```
public void sendCommand(String command){
    {
        String line;
         try{
             while((line = consoleOutput.readLine())!= null)
                {
                     System.out.println(line);
                                     pin.write("\r\n".getBytes());//Added line
                     if(line.equals("rkscli:") || line.equals("password :") || line.equals("Please login: ")){
                         pin.write((command + "\n\r").getBytes());
                     }
                }
             }
```

It will not hang at the bufferedReader.readline() but will go through and skip the write (It does not seem to write anything to the shell and sometimes it will and is not predictable)

Any ideas as to what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe that I resolved the problem by reading every character (character by character) rather than doing a read line because since its a shell it will never give a terminating (null) character "/00" and if I am not mistaken the read line looks for that and will continue to wait until it finds it therefore blocking and not continuing.

here is the revised code:

```
 line = new StringBuilder();
                 boolean ready = false;
                 int c = 0;
                        Thread.sleep(1000);//needs to sleep, it isnt ready :(
                        while((ready = consoleOutput.ready()) == true){
                            ready = consoleOutput.ready();
                            c = consoleOutput.read();//read char by char
                            line.append((char)c);
                            if((char)c == ':' && (c=consoleOutput.read()) == 0x20 && (consoleOutput.ready()!= true)){
                                pin.write((command + "\n\r").getBytes());//writing after ready
                                pin.flush();
                                System.out.println(line.toString() + command);
                                line = null;
                                break;
                            }
```

The weird issue I had when I wrote something to the shell in my first question where it would continue to read line and not block when I wrote anything to the shell was because it was reading that and reading the line.