# jsch shell select a menu option

Tags: shell, input, jsch

I am experiencing an issue with my program where when I hit a certain menu I am unable to enter in an option. The menu looks like a prompt with a pre-selected option where one is able to change the option by over writing it.
Here is what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see 3 is already selected. I simply want to over write it and enter in another option.
When I simply try to write an option to it and print out what the shell it it gives me this when I do a system.out.println:

```
set encryption home
Wireless Encryption Type:[0] quit, [1] OPEN, [2] WEP, or [3] WPA
Wireless Encryption Type: 31
```

It will simply do option 3 and ignor the "1" and will read the "\r\n" I have in the command I sent (which was "1\r\n"). In between there is a character which is not represented here it is character 0x08. How can I get my program to overwrite the default option?

Things I have tried:
I have tried doing \n\r
semicolon ;
\n\r before the command
\r
ommiting \r\n (this causes the program to never go past the wireless encryption type because it did not enter anything).
I have no idea what to do next with this. Any ideas?

ps: I am using a pipedinput to enter in all of the commands as suggested by [nilbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194439/sending-commands-to-server-via-jsch-shell-channel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem, the shell did not like the /n/r and counted each one as an enter. so it works once i removed either the /r or the /n. currently I have it at /n, hope this helps someone!