# How to read file in Unix directory using Java?

Tags: java, unix, jsch

I have  a file in unix directory that I need to read and display content of it to the page. I am using jcraft library in my java code. I am able to connect to Unix server and find the file but can’t read it. I found sample code to read a file but it isn’t working, it dies on the int c = in.read()line, probably stuck in the loop…  I am posting my code may be you can spot a problem. If there are other(better) ways to do it I would appreciate an example. Hope my question and sample code it clear enough. Thanks all.

```
public String readFile(String path) throws Exception {

    ChannelExec c = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
    OutputStream os = c.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
    c.setCommand("scp -f " + path); //path is something like /home/username/sample.txt
    c.connect();
    String header = readLine(is);

    int length = Integer.parseInt(header.substring(6, header.indexOf(' ', 6)));
    os.write(0);
    os.flush();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    length = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    os.write(0);
    os.flush();

    c.disconnect();

    return new String(buffer);  
}

private String readLine(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (;;) {
        int c = in.read(); // code stops working here
        if (c == '\n') {
            return baos.toString();
        } else if (c == -1) {
            throw new IOException("End of stream");
        } else {
            baos.write(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can not read means?? post the error..

Comment: there isn't an error, it just stops at int c = in.read(); line and nothing happens(no errors, no warnings...) but code will not continue

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into using `ChannelSftp` instead of `ChannelExec`:

```
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
try {
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    channelSftp.connect();
    is = channelSftp.get(path);
    // read the contents, etc...
} finally {
    if (channelSftp != null) {
        channelSftp.exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks alright. I am assuming it simply hangs (like you said) at the read.

> [...] This method blocks until input data is available [...]

I am thinking you are having trouble establishing the channel. 
Is the `scp` possibly waiting for your password or something?

---

On second thought your line detection might not work. This would result in the for jumping beyond where you would want it to exit. Maybe you should also check for `'\r'` too.

---

Also somebody did something similar here:
[How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902386/how-to-read-jsch-command-output)