# Capture server command output using JSch and Java

Tags: java, ssh, stdout, jsch

I am using JSch to ssh to multiple servers and run few commands. My output file capture everything. But I am looking for a way to capture only the server respond.

Code:

```
try (OutputStream log = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("OUTPUT_FILE"))) {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    for (String host : jssh.listOfhost()) {
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(getProperties());
        session.connect(10 * 1000);

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setOutputStream(log, true);

        try (PipedInputStream commandSource = new PipedInputStream();
             OutputStream commandSink = new PipedOutputStream(commandSource)) {

            CommandSender sender = new CommandSender(commandSink);
            Thread sendThread = new Thread(sender);
            sendThread.start();

            channel.setInputStream(commandSource);
            channel.connect(15 * 1000);

            sendThread.join();
            if (sender.exception != null) {
                throw sender.exception;
            }
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Current Output:

```
Last login: Thu Jan 14 15:06:17 2016 from 192.168.1.4
mypc:~ user$ 
mypc:~ user$ hostname
mypc
mypc:~ user$ df -l | grep disk0s3 |tr -s [:blank:]|cut -d ' ' -f 7
19098537
```

but I only want to output the following

```
mypc 19098537
```

Which is an outcome of the following two commands

```
hostname
df -l | grep disk0s3 |tr -s [:blank:]|cut -d ' ' -f 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exec` channel, not `shell` channel. The `exec` channel is intended for command execution. The `shell` channel is intended for implementing an interactive session. That's why you get all the prompts and such. You do not get these in the `exec` channel.

See the [official JSCh example for using `exec` channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html).

If you need to read both stdout and stderr, see my answer to [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848)