# Execute 'sudo su -' with JSch

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to become to root with `sudo su -` but when execute it standby the console, it show me this:

> Connected
>
> #

And there not pass the next line.

This my code:

```java
String command1 = "sudo su -";

try {

    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected");

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);

    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    channel.connect();

    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
    System.out.println("DONE");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When you do sudo su, it will ask for password.

Comment: replace your command with `sudo su -u username`. I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: This has been asked many times already. Please google your problem before posting a question. -- See for example [Running command after sudo login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670999/850848) or [Executing sudo using SSH “exec” channel in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52481755/850848).

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su -` command opens a new shell process inside your current shell.

This new shell process will not end until it receives an `exit` command.

Since you are issuing commands from Java to another process in the OS, the result is the same as if you issued a command that hanged.

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Use `sudo` only to execute the exact commands you really need by appending `sudo` to every command.
2. Create a wrapper script that will execute all commands you need to run as root and run that with `sudo`.

Comment: @AntonioRomeroElvira glad to hear the solution worked for you. Could you pleas mark the answer as "accepted". Thanks.