# JSch multiple tunnels/jumphosts

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm not sure if this is caused by using a private key instead of password for the port forwarding but here's what I'm trying to do

[image]

I need to forward local port 3308 all the way to the my SQL DB at 3306.

I can run things like this all together in terminal on my local

```
ssh -L 3308:localhost:3307 username@jumpbox "ssh -L 3307:mysqlDB:3306 username@server"
```

Or run the first part on my local and then the second part on the jumpbox. Both works fine and I can connect to my localhost:3308.

The problem comes when I start using JSch. Here is my code

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");

Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "jumpbox");
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect();

int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(3308, "localhost", 3307);
Session mysqlSession = jsch.getSession("username", "server", assinged_port);
mysqlSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
mysqlSession.connect(); // Connection timed out here
mysqlSession.setPortForwardingL(3307, "mysqlDB", 3306);
```

The first connection is done but the second one timed out.

> Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

Am I doing something wrong here with JSch or port forwarding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ssh` command is making use of an SSH client (another `ssh`) running on "jump box".

When you want to implement the same using Java, you have two options:

1. Do the same in Java, i.e. use `session` to run `ssh -L 3307:mysqlDB:3306 username@server` on the "jump box".

   See [Executing a command using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42195535/850848).

   Though, I do not think you should rely on `ssh` program for the second jump, for the same reason you use Java/JSch for the first jump (and not `ssh` program).
2. Avoid using a separate `ssh` tool, and instead open the other SSH session locally via yet another forwarded port. You can actually do the same using recent versions of `ssh`, with [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J) (supported since OpenSSH 7.3):

   ```
   ssh -L 3308:mysqlDB:3306 -J username@jumpbox username@server
   ```

   See also [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)

   I prefer this approach.

---

To implement the latter approach:

- You have to forward some local port to `server:22`, so that you can open SSH connection to the `server`:

  ```
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");

  Session jumpboxSession = jsch.getSession("username", "jumpbox");
  jumpboxSession.connect();

  int serverSshPort = jumpboxSession.setPortForwardingL(0, "server", 22);
  Session serverSession = jsch.getSession("username", "localhost", serverSshPort);
  serverSession.connect();
  ```
- Then you forward another local port via `server` to MySQL port:

  ```
  int mysqlPort = serverSession.setPortForwardingL(0, "mysqlDB", 3306);
  ```

  Now you should be able to connect to `localhost:mysqlPort` using MySQL client.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).*

*For a correct (and secure) approach, see:

[How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)*