# Command using ChannelExec not executed - Jsch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using Jsch to create a file in the server and execute some commands. For the file creation, it's working fine, however, for the command execution, doesn't. It keeps the status -1 (still working on it) and keep there forever. This happen for shell execution or when I try to became root. Follow the method used below:

```
public void upload(String localPath) throws IOException {
    Session session = connectToServer();
    System.out.println("In upload");
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = getChannelToSftpServer(session);

    //Creating file in temporary location
    File f = new File(localPath);
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);

    // Creating file on server and setting the permissions to the user (chmod 777)

    if (channelSftp != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Change working in temp directory");
            changeWorkingDirectory(channelSftp, TEMP_PATH);
            
            ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            //THE PROBLEM ALSO HAPPENS WHEN EXECUTING A SHELL WITH THIS COMMAND INSIDE
            channelExec.setCommand(
                "root command (using pbrun) <command is here, confidential> "); 
            InputStream commandOutput = channelExec.getInputStream();
            channelExec.connect();

            StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            int readByte = commandOutput.read();

            while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
            {
               outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
               readByte = commandOutput.read();
               System.out.println(outputBuffer);
            }
            System.out.println("Root connected.");
            channelExec.disconnect();
            
            channelSftp.put(fi, f.getName());
            channelSftp.chmod(0777, localPath);
            channelSftp.chown(123, localPath);
            channelSftp.chgrp(123, localPath);
            
            System.out.println("File configurations changed.");
            
            //Copying to the official path
            channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            channelExec.setCommand("mv /tmp/"+f.getName()+" "+path);
            channelExec.connect();
            System.out.println("File is completed and ready!");
            
            while (channelExec.getExitStatus() == -1) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                
            }
            channelExec.disconnect();

        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException(e.getStackTrace() + "");
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            disconnectChanneltoSftpServer(channelSftp);
            session.disconnect();
            fi.close();
            // Deletes the local File.
            f.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `getInputStream()` before calling `connect()`.

And you actually better read both stderr and stdout to get the errors.
For that, see my answer to [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848)