# Commands endlessly executing in eclipse using JSCH

Tags: jsch

I am executing below code to establish a ssh connection to linux vm and execute commands using jsch from eclipse. code is like below:

```
try{
        
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession("prkotagi", "slc10gst.us.oracle.com", 22);
        session.setPassword("P@rs@1234nth");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        
        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
          while(in.available()>0){
            int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if(i<0)break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
          }
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
          }
          try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the issue here i am facing is when i execute the command in linux vm using eclispe. In eclipse the programm is running indefinitely like 30 mins. But actually the command should take 1 to 2 mins and it is showing log in my console. but the execution is getting strucked.

How to quit the command execution as soon as we got the o/p and the new line with bash $ displayed. But eclipse is not ending the execution.

Comment: Where does it stuck exactly? What output do you get? Is it stdout or stderr?

Comment: Also try this code instead: [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848).