# Running a script on JSch channel but it doesn't throw an exception when script is not found

Tags: java, groovy, ssh, jsch, ioexception

I am running a bash script in Groovy by creating a JSch tunnel to a remote host and running the script on a defined path there with a couple of arguments. It works fine but I want it to throw an exception when I script is not found. When i manually try to run the script on the remote server when the script is absent, I get "No such file or directory" error. But I cannot see that error anywhere when I run the script through JSch. The other couple of Exceptions like "`Auth failed`" or "`Connection timed out`" work fine.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*


                    //Connecting to JSch individual sessions
                    JSch jsch = new JSch();
                    jsch.addIdentity( "~/.ssh/id_rsa" );
                    jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, host, REMOTE_PORT);
                    jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                    jschSession.connect();
                    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) jschSession.openChannel("exec");
                    log.info("Channel is open");
                    //Run the shell script with given parameters
                    channelExec.setCommand("sh " + pathtoscript + " \"" + arg1 + "\" "  + arg2);
                    channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);//Not really sure if this works on Groovy?
                    channelExec.connect();

                    InputStream inp = channelExec.getInputStream();
                    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                    String shellOut = "";
                    while (true) {
                            while (inp.available() > 0) {
                                    int i = inp.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                                    if (i < 0) {
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    shellOut= new String(tmp, 0, i);
                                    log.info(shellOut); //prints out the output when script is run
                            }
                            if (channelExec.isClosed()) {
                                    if (inp.available() > 0) {
                                            continue;
                                    }
                                    log.info("exit-status: " + channelExec.getExitStatus()); //keeps giving me exist-status as 127 when script is not found but I also want it to throw an exception which it doesn't
                                    break;
                            }
                            try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                                            log.error("This is the error of input");
                            }
                    }

                    channelExec.disconnect();
            }

            catch(JSchException ex) {
                    log.error("Exception cause is: " + ex.getCause());
                    if(ex.getCause().toString().contains("Connection timed out")){
                            log.info("Connection timed out on " + obj.ipAddress);
                            //do something
                   }else(ex.getMessage().contains("Auth fail")){
                            log.info("Authorization failed on " + obj.ipAddress);
                            //do something

                   }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Catching exception", e);
                    e.printStackTrace(); //I thought this would print the "Script not found" exception but it doesn't
            }
```

This is the output when I create a JSch channel and run the script when the script is absent:

```
Creating JSch tunnel...
Channel is open
exit-status: 127
Session disconnected.
```

Comment: As usually, no feedback from you! You just keep posting new questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw an exception when the command produces an error output, you have to read the error output and convert it to an exception. The `channelExec.setErrStream(System.err)` won't do that for you.

For a complete code for reading all of command's output, see [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848)

At the end of that code, you have the error output in `errorBuffer.toString()`. Instead of printing it, you will want to throw an exception.

You might also want to check the [`Channel.getExitStatus`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus--). A non-zero exit code typically indicates an error.