# How to figure out if a command executed using JSch in Java has successfully completed?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am not able to figure out whether a command has completed its execution or not before sending the next command using the JSch library in Java.

Code snippet

```
// Opens a new channel of type 'exec'
Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec"); 
// sets the command to be executed
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command); 
// Gets an input stream for this channel
InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream(); 
channel.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

When executing commands, there are two sources you can use to decide if the command failed:

- Command exit code. That's [`Channel.getExitStatus`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus--) in JSch. Note that the method returns an actual exit code, once the command *finishes* only.
- Command error output. That's [`Channel.getExtInputStream`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExtInputStream--) in JSch.

For an example how to read both, see [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848)