# SFTP file transfer using Java JSch

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, file-transfer, jsch

Here is my code, which retrieves content of the file, on the remote server and display as output.

```
package sshexample;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SSHexample 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String host = "192.168.100.103";
    int port=22;

    String remoteFile="sample.txt";

    try
    {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
        System.out.println("Creating SFTP Channel.");
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
        System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");
        InputStream out= null;
        out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
        sftpChannel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(JSchException | SftpException | IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Now how to implement this program that the file is copied in the localhost and how to copy a file from localhost to the server.

Here how to make work the transfer of files for any format of files.

Answer (score 22):

The most trivial way to upload a file over SFTP with JSch is:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();

ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel.connect();

sftpChannel.put("C:/source/local/path/file.zip", "/target/remote/path/file.zip");
```

Similarly for a download:

```
sftpChannel.get("/source/remote/path/file.zip", "C:/target/local/path/file.zip");
```

---

*You may need to [deal with `UnknownHostKey` exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848#32858953).*

Answer (score 7):

Usage:

```
sftp("file:/C:/home/file.txt", "ssh://user:pass@host/home");
sftp("ssh://user:pass@host/home/file.txt", "file:/C:/home");
```

[Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37067557/448078)

Answer (score 4):

Below code works for me

```
   public static void sftpsript(String filepath) {

 try {
  String user ="demouser"; // username for remote host
  String password ="demo123"; // password of the remote host

   String host = "demo.net"; // remote host address
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.connect();

  ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
  sftpChannel.connect();

  sftpChannel.put("I:/demo/myOutFile.txt", "/tmp/QA_Auto/myOutFile.zip");
  sftpChannel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
 }catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
   }
```

**OR using StrictHostKeyChecking as "NO" (security consequences)**

```
public static void sftpsript(String filepath) {

 try {
  String user ="demouser"; // username for remote host
  String password ="demo123"; // password of the remote host

   String host = "demo.net"; // remote host address
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
   Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
   Properties config = new Properties();
   config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
   session.setConfig(config);;
   session.setPassword(password);
   System.out.println("user=="+user+"\n host=="+host);
   session.connect();

  ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
  sftpChannel.connect();

  sftpChannel.put("I:/demo/myOutFile.txt", "/tmp/QA_Auto/myOutFile.zip");
  sftpChannel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
 }catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
   }
```

Comment: Do not suggest to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` without explaining security consequences. You are loosing protection against [MIMT attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so!

Comment: done martin .. but for me code is not executing without StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" .. some RSA related error occurred .. any suggestions ?

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15108923/850848#47091705) links to [another question that explain how to correctly deal with hostkeys in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848#32858953).