# download remote file to local directory in windows

Tags: java, windows, ssh, download, cmd

I have 2 windows machines: windows 7 and windows 2008 server R2.
I am looking for a way to download a remote file from one windows machine to another using Java JSCH lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [copy command](https://superuser.com/a/197294) giving instead of both arguments IPs to your windows machines:

```
copy  \\first_windows_machine\c$\dest_file.txt \\second_windows_machine\c$\download_folder\
```

first_windows_machine - is the one from where you want to take the file 
second_windows_mahcine - where you want to save that file

For implementing this in java, you can use answer from here: [file transfer using java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31676547/4568806)

Comment: Thank you, I handled my issue using sources from your answer, will add a full answer for archive.