# Java: how to move a file form a windows to a linux server?

Tags: java, file, samba

As title says, I need to move a file from a windows server to a linux one.
If I would need to move files between two windows locations, I'll use the renameTo method of class File.
As I have found out searching on the web, I have used the JCIFS library, using the renameTo method og class SmbFile. This works for renaming two SmbFile. But i have a File and a SmbFile!
Is there any way to do this besides copying the file content byte by byte (using BufferedReader and SmbFileOutputStream)?

Comment: Look for JSch library, you can FTP file from windows to linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108923/sftp-file-transfer-using-java-jsch