# Maintaining a SSH channel in Java with JSCH

Tags: java, ssh, client, jsch

I want to control a remote system in Java via SSH using JSCH.
The front end is a simple button GUI which triggers the execution of a command.
Some of the controls are time critical, there should be no big delay between button press and command execution.

My problem:
Every time a new channel is opened, the back-end needs about 8 seconds to initialize until the command is executed. (The back-end interface is implemented with RBSH afaik)

If I run a normal session via a console client, everything runs fine without bigger delays.

My question:
Is there a way to initialize a channel to execute some commands and read the output(and only the command output) back sequentially?

I already figured out that `session.openChannel("shell")` could give the desired functionality, but I cant figure out how to do that properly.

**EDIT**: I'm not tied to JSCH. If there's another library which can do that, I'm also open for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [any good jsch examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/any-good-jsch-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You want an "exec" channel rather than a "shell" channel. SCP uses an exec channel, so look at [one of the SCP examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html) or [one of the SCP libraries](https://github.com/willwarren/jscp) on the Internet.

Alternately, if you control the remote server, you could define a "subsystem" for the command that you want to run, and run it through a subsystem channel. The big difference between an exec channel and a subsystem is who specifies the command to be executed. An exec channel will execute a command provided by the client. With a subsystem, the client just requests the subsystem by name, and the server runs the correct command (or provides the service in some other way). SFTP uses a subsystem called "sftp-server", so you could look at how Jsch's SFTP classes are implemented.

Comment: If I get it right, both exec examples including closing the channel after the execution of a command. This is the case I have to avoid since every channel opening takes 8 seconds. For the subsystem idea: I have no control about the remote ssh implementation, it's a closed system.

Comment: Does it take 8 seconds _just_ to open a channel, or are you opening a new session each time as well? If it's taking 8 seconds to open any kind of channel, then maybe you should concentrate on fixing that. If you're stuck with this 8-second behavior, then there are ways to open a channel once and then run a sequence of commands without closing it.

Comment: Have a look at this [example class](http://pastebin.com/F50640fV) The result of the call is http://pastebin.com/u5kAccaD