# Kill process before disconnecting

Tags: java, jsch

I am using Jsch to tail a server-log. When I close my exec-channel and session, the "tail -f ..." process still stays alive at server side.

I tried to do `channel.sendSignal("KILL")` but it throws an exception:

`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request`

how can I do a clean disconnect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old post but I'm posting my solution in case someone needs it.

After some testing I learned that I had to send the int value of the signal instead of the string:

```
channel.sendSignal("2"); // CTRL + C - interrupt
channel.sendSignal("9"); // KILL
```

For more signals scroll to 'Standard signals' on [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) page.

I'm using the following methods to send and interrupt commands.
They are slightly modified versions of the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/any-good-jsch-examples).

```
public String sendCommand(String command)
{
  StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

  try
  {
    Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
    channel.connect();
    InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();

    int readByte = commandOutput.read();
    while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
    {
      outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
      readByte = commandOutput.read();
      if (interrupt)
      {
        interruptChannel(channel);
        break;
      }
    }

    channel.disconnect();
  }
  catch(IOException ioX)
  {
    logWarning(ioX.getMessage());
    outputBuffer.append(ioX.getMessage());
    return null;
  }
  catch(JSchException jschX)
  {
    logWarning(jschX.getMessage());
    outputBuffer.append(jschX.getMessage());
  }
  finally
  {
    setInterrupt(false);
  }

  return outputBuffer.toString();
}

private void interruptChannel(Channel _channel)
{
  try
  {
    _channel.sendSignal("2");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    logger.error("Failed interrupting channel", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: sadly, it throws the same exception. but if this works for you, the mistake seems to be on my side...
anyway, i will close this question.
last remark: even documentation says to send "Signal without SIG prefix" (see here: http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html).

Comment: I got an exception when sending "INT" but with "2" it worked. I have updated my post with the methods I'm using to send commands and signals.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** with `implementation 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'` on a Dropbear ssh server, `channel.sendSignal("KILL")` worked, while `channel.sendSignal("9")` did absolutely nothing.