# how to change ebs volume inside .property file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

i am new in aws.

i created one ec2 instance and installed tomcat7, deployed java web application. after i want change inside my application like db.property file. how to change through java api.

my all files are available in ebs volume. how to get particular file and modify and update through java programmatic.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1):

The AWS API doesn't let you access EBS volume contents directly. You need to log into the machine and make the changes.
If it's a Linux machine, you can do so via SSH.

You can use a command-line SSH client or an SSH client library, such as Jsch for Java.

Comment: thanks.  give me any sample code about SSH client library.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/any-good-jsch-examples)