# Java - Run shell command over SSH using public key file

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to execute the shell script on the remote server in Java. For SSH connectivity in Java, I referred this link: [Run a command over SSH with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/run-a-command-over-ssh-with-jsch). But it talks about providing the username, password information. In my case, I want to provide the public key file. Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: @Seraph: I am trying to do the SSH connectivity using .pem file. I could not find it there.

Comment: @Swaps That's what the accepted answer shows!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyPath);        
session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
```

You can convert ppk to pem and vice-versa using Putty keygen tool if you're on Windows. I am sure there would a similar utility for Linux.

Comment: You don't need keyboard or password authentications if you're sending a public key over...

Comment: @Makoto: So do you mean if I have the .pem file, do I need to ignore the second parameter of `session.setConfig()`?

Comment: @Swaps: A .pem isn't a public key.  You'll have to convert that first.

Comment: I think that was for passphrases. But, you can ignore it.

Comment: This answer shows exactly what the accepted answer to duplicate questions shows. Please do not duplicate information. Vote for this question to be closed as a duplicate instead.