# Which Java Telnet or openSSH library?

Tags: java, telnet, openssh

I need to make a small test program in java which has to communicate with remote Windows server using telnet, or openSSH. Which library would you suggest to use? I'd like to use a well documented and stable library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) (and do). 
It's not too large to learn quickly. It's used in:

1. Ant(1.6 or later).
2. JSch has been used for Ant's sshexec
   and scp tasks.
3. Eclipse(3.0).
4. Our Eclipse-CVSSSH2 plug-in has been
   included in Eclipse SDK 3.0. This
   plug-in will allow you to get ssh2
   accesses to remote CVS repository by
   JSch.
5. NetBeans 5.0(and later)
6. Jakarta Commons VFS
7. Maven Wagon
8. Rational Application Devloper for
   WebSphere Software
9. HP Storage Essentials
10. JIRA

and, it has X-forwarding and such to work with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also asked about Telnet [Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) provides an implementation.

Comment: not sure if you still need a solution but I made something [simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988029/java-telnet-library/14098926#14098926) (and EXTREMELY limited in scope) that might help

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend JTA, the Java Terminal Adapter. Very nice plugin architecture if you have to add value to it.