# Telnet Client - Java

Tags: java, telnet

I want to write a telnet client using java; I would like to know what stuff I need to look out for or implement to make such an application. Are there any particular classes that I should look in to?

Comment: Do you want to practice Java network programming or do you want to write a good telnet client?

Comment: Its for a project; it must be good but they do not expect it to be to sophisticated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Java Telnet or openSSH library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715406/which-java-telnet-or-openssh-library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A telnet client is just line based communication with a telnet server. The basics is covered by

- [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)
- [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)
- [PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

What extra features do you need?

Comment: Not really. Many severs will send you Telnet commands, which you certainly cannot even read with a `Rder`..

Comment: @EJP This is some serious spelunking. I'm not even sure what your comment addresses. Yes, a telnet server might send other stuff.

Comment: I am referring to Telnet commands, which are transmitted in binary, and which therefore won't be read correctly by a `Reader`. This is rather basic Telnet information.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) offers probably everything you need. You may want to have a look at an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ExampleofuseofTelnetClient.htm).

Comment: I would like to do the application without using third part libraries

Comment: Interesting. So you may want to have a look at the sources to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at a dozen or more RFCs covering the Telnet protocol and its various options, sorting out which of those you actually need, which are historical, which are just fantasies that were never implemented, etc etc etc. Good luck. It's quite a substantial piece of research.

Or do as the others have suggested and use an existing implementation. Have a look at the Java Terminal Adapter for one that I've been using with great success for several years now.