# Location of Sample Code for Java Driving Telnet at a High Level

Tags: java, testing, automation, driver, telnet

I have looked at several questions here about using Java to drive a telnet session, and although I see some code down at the socket/protocol level, and a few recommendations for this or that telnet library, I don't see sample code or a pointer to sample code for driving a telnet session using one of those libraries.  There's no reason why it can't be this easy:

```
MyTel session = new MyTel("host.myco");
session.start();
session.waitForThenType("login:", "imauser");
session.waitForThenType("Password:","secr3et");
String output = session.waitForThenType("Solaris", "tail MyFile.txt");
session.waitForThenType("%>","exit");
session.end();
// enjoy output here
```

So, looking for some example code that stays out of the telnet sockets and protocol, but can drive telnet sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Which Java Telnet or openSSH library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715406/which-java-telnet-or-openssh-library)

http://sadun-util.sourceforge.net/telnet_library.html

The sadun code is part of a larger set of utilities.  What you need are these files:

```
com.deltax.util (all)
org.sadun.util.tp (all)
org.sadun.util
> Cache.java
> ClassResolver.java
> OperationTimedoutException.java
> TelnetInputStream.java
> TelnetInputStreamConsumer.java
> TelnetNVTChannel.java
> Terminable.java
> UnixLoginHandler.java
```

That will allow you to write a program similar to the one in the question:

```
Socket s = new Socket("host.myco", 23);
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
UnixLoginHandler handler = new UnixLoginHandler(s);
TelnetInputStreamConsumer is = handler.doLogin("imauser","secre3t");
System.out.println(is.consumeInput(10000));
is.setConsumptionOperationsTimeout(10000);
w.write("tail MyFile.txt\r\n");w.flush();
String output = is.consumeByCriteria(new TelnetInputStreamConsumer.ContainsStringCriterium("$ "));
handler.doLogout();
System.out.println("output:\n" + output);
```

Comment: I was looking for telnet.  That link looks pretty good.  I'm going to play with it now.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem--remember to upvote or accept answers; it's what keeps the site going :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/). In particular, their [`TelnetClient`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html) class.

See also:

- [Java - Writing An Automated Telnet Client](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/12/22/java-writing-an-automated-telnet-client/)

I've implemented my own telnet client class that simply wraps the one provided by Apache. It's extensible and easy-to-use.

Note:

The only problem I encountered was disabling echo. For more information, see my unresolved question:

- [How to disable echo when sending a terminal command using apache-commons-net TelnetClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410579/how-to-disable-echo-when-sending-a-terminal-command-using-apache-commons-net-teln)