# Tomcat JNDI through SSH connect database

Tags: database, tomcat, ssh, jndi

I want connect to my remote database through SSH in my local tomcat,just like Navicat connect remote database through SSH.

How to configure it? In Resource lab?

Comment: You have to set up an SSH port forwarding tunnel yourself (on the machine that runs Tomcat). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524275/connect-to-an-oracle-db-in-jdbc-over-an-ssh-tunnel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use vpn to solved this problem.