# ssh client in j2me

Tags: java-me, ssh

I have to develop a minimal ssh client in j2me, and time is not a luxury.
It would be helpful if you guys got any links(libraries or documentation) so that i could take off right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just use [MidpSSH](http://www.xk72.com/midpssh/)? It's open source, GPL-licensed, and unless you'd want to bundle it with proprietary software, it could be an excellent alternative.

Comment: Why don't you want to use MidpSSH sources as a reference? If not, may be you could at least opt to use various SSH implementations in Java? Or you *absolutely* need to implement it by yourself from scratch, using only SSH protocol documentation?

Comment: Well, looks like almost any SSH library for _Java_ (not just for J2ME) will do - for example, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java - there's a good overview of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There is [MidpSSH](http://www.xk72.com/midpssh/), a mobile SSH client for MIDP devices. It's GPL licensed, the source code is available at the linked website. The license may not be compatible with your deployment scenario, but it's still a good source to get started.