# How to convert telnet to SSH

Tags: ssh

Currently my application is using telnet to connect to server. The java file is using commands like:-

```
login()
waitfor("$")
send()
```

What are the corresponding commands i need to use for SSH connections and what all things i have to do to convert this telnet to SSH? Please help..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java) should be of help?