# How to read a text file from a remote server location

Tags: java

I have a text file with the name textfile1.txt in C: location and this file conatains in a server machine  and the machine ip is 1.127.0.0,

I want to read this text file in my java application and display the content,

Please help me in this,

Thanks in Advance,

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: try connect to host with specific adress?

Comment: Show us what you tried to do, please.

Comment: I have the same problem... though my file is not named `textfile1.txt`, the remote file I'm after is called `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the file in a shared folder on the server, and use standard java IO to reference that filepath, e.g. `\\<your server ip>\shared\textfile1.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the file to your local machine and read it from there.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java/996415#996415) could help you do it.