# SSH client and server in java

Tags: java, ssh

Which are the popular libraries to use to implement both custom SSH client and server in java?

I'm aware that Jsch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is a popular java ssh client, are there good and secure java ssh servers that have an open source license?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Answer (score 3):

#### [Apache Mina server](http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html)

I haven't checked it out but apparently it has support for:

- Port forwarding
- SFTP
- X11 Forwarding
- Agent forwarding

#### [NSsh](http://nssh.codeplex.com/)

I know this is the wrong language but this C# server is partly based off the [Ganymed client code](http://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/) and might be a good reference if Apache Mina doesn't work out.