# Start a java application from a remote computer using ssh protocol

Tags: java, ssh

I want to start my java app remotely. I'd like to use the SSH protocol as a way to communicate.  Is there a library that will help do this?

Answer (score 0):

[SSH client and server in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583507/ssh-client-and-server-in-java)

But I would use just ssh support built in the system, so you connect to the box with ssh and then just use terminal to access command-line console of your java app.