# SSH Terminal in a Browser or Panel java or groovy

Tags: java, groovy

is it possible to run the ssh terminal in a browser, or Panel  using java or groovy

Comment: See [SSH library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search [reveals JCTerm, an SSH2 Terminal Emulator in Pure Java](http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/), which is:

> JCTerm(JCraft's Term) is a pure Java VT100 terminal emulator for SSH2.
>   This terminal emulator also allows you to enjoy port forwarding, X11
>   forwarding, etc. JCTerm is licensed under GNU LGPL and easily
>   integrated into your programs.