# Using java Runtime (on a windows machine) to send a linux command to a linux server

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

below is the piece of code I am running. whether I use an array pf string (cmd) or it is 
a single string I get an exception (see further down) while there is a passwordless login to the target Linux system.

```
private static int bringHostFile() {
    try {            
        String[] cmd ={"ssh" , "root@im6-64s" , "/root/bring_hosts"};
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        String s = null;
        // read the output from the command
        if ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);     
         }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(s);
        }            

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }   

    return 0;  
}
```

The exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ssh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:471)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:604)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:442)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:339)
    at JavaRunCommand.CommandGetCurrentCPUSize(JavaRunCommand.java:140)
    at EC.<init>(EC.java:29)
```

Any idea what is the cause ?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified": is `ssh` in your program's %PATH%?

Comment: Or, you do not have a `ssh` client installed on your Windows machine.

Comment: You can specify the full path of the `ssh` if its not in your path.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this in a portable manner would be to use a pure Java SSH implementation

[Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is one of them, and a good one

It'll avoid you to cope with classpath/environnement problems while letting you send any command you want to your remote box

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have ssh client, and it's in %PATH% (try open 'cmd' and exec ssh from there). 
you can also use putty or cygwin for that, or the most recommended way- use java library: [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)