# Get file system structure of hosts on the same LAN

Tags: java

Is it possible for a JAVA application to get the file system directory structure of another host on the same LAN?

For example:

Machines A and B are on the same LAN. A is the localhost and B is the remote host. Is it possible for a JAVA application executing on A to get the directory structure (essentially a 'ls -R') of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by issuing the `ls -R` command over the `ssh` protocol.

For `ssh` library recommendations, see [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Comment: thanks. If I use ssh, will the target host also need to grant permission?

Comment: @czchlong: Yes. Whatever solution you choose, it will require some cooperation from the target system.

Comment: lol...that begs the question...is there a way to prevent the target host from having to grant permission? XP

Comment: @czchlong: Not if the target host is half-secure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although you'd have to use something like SSH to open a remote terminal session to execute the `ls` command.  There's no way to natively do that with just Java without opening a socket and machine B somehow cooperating with the request. (That would be a huge security hole if you could...)