# How to make call from android to a server ip address

Tags: android, hadoop

I have to code in android for making an application which makes a call to an hadoop cluster node. I have an ip adress for the same i can login via putty on my windows machine.
I dont know how to make a call to that server from my android app?
And, how to run a executable jar file deployed on the hadoop node.

Any guidance or a sample code piece will be a big help.

Thanks in advance
Manu Misra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you want to login via SSH and execute a command on a server?

The better way would be to write a small 'server app', that provides an interface via http to start the processing. (You might have a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/))

If you prefer ssh, you should have a look at [ssh java libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java).

Comment: Sintara seems to be Ruby based web application development tool. whereas I am looking for interacting via android application. But the second opinion given by you as ssh java libraries seems to be useful.  Thanks a lot for guidance