# Any alternative for Rundeck for running commands on multiple servers?

Tags: java, rundeck

I am implementing a workflow of tasks in a Java program.
One of the tasks is running some commands on multiple Linux servers.

The servers are determined dynamically - read from an XML file.
I examined Rundeck's API, but it seems that I have to configure the servers in advance, which doesn't suit my needs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One answer is to use rundeck, I think you just need rundeck to dynamically load your nodes.

To make it dynamic you need to refresh the project. Simply restart rundeck or use the [api refresh method](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/index.html#refreshing-resources-for-a-project). I haven't tried the latter which I think is the better solution. The [Resource Model](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/rundeck-basics.html#resource-model) supports files and getting your node list of servers from an external source URL.

But if your are rolling your own a better answer maybe SSH and consider a [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using an external API look into using JSCAPE's [SSH Factory for Java](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/ssh-factory/). Documentation can be located [here](http://files.jscape.com/sshfactory/docs/html/index.html?overview19.html).