# How to do unix commands or operations of unix in java

Tags: java

How to connect to unix server and perform operation in java as we performed in unix screen.
I wnat to execute this command "**sed '1,2d;/affected/d;/^$/d;/------/d'**" in java.

Comment: Do you want to execute the command in the local machine or a remote one?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: want to execute in remote one

Answer (score 1):

These are actually two questions.

How to execute a system command in Java. For that you can use [`Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sed '1,2d;/affected/d;/^$/d;/------/d' file.txt");
p.waitFor();
```

How to execute a command on a remote machine. This could be done with [`ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1)

```
ssh user@example.com "sed '1,2d;/affected/d;/^$/d;/------/d' file.txt"
```

For that to work, you must have `ssh` installed, of course.