# How can I get the SHA of a GitHub commit in Java?

Tags: java, git, github

I'd like to know if there is a hacky method to obtain a commit SHA of the latest commit of a branch in a particular GitHub repo in Java. As far as I have seen, the GitHub API only has a hook to access the full commit info, not just the API. Anybody have any ways to do this?

Comment: This looks like it should be possible using the [refs API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) and a tiny bit of JSON parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [refs api](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference), as suggested by cjc343:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref
```

For example:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/git/refs/heads/master

{
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/git/refs/heads/master",
  "object": {
    "sha": "d991ef2ab1b4d156c7e5d33d052d66f8eaafc460",
    "type": "commit",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/git/commits>/d991ef2ab1b4d156c7e5d33d052d66f8eaafc460"
  }
}
```

You can either extract `object.sha` after parsing this as JSON or, in the spirit of "hacky", pipe through:

```
| grep \"sha\": | cut -f4 -d\"
```

to get:

```
d991ef2ab1b4d156c7e5d33d052d66f8eaafc460
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want (no Java). However, using [java based ssh-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java) and the following commands you can achieve this.

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:<github username>/<git project name>.git
```

Following is a sample output:

```
4de51ba41fba357ac9ce63f098451cd1fc2dacbe        HEAD
4de51ba41fba357ac9ce63f098451cd1fc2dacbe        refs/heads/master
cc42dc12a972dab122030b046440f47e0485e321        refs/pull/1/head
73629fe86def6fef896abd32637b97fddf8cd3b4        refs/pull/1/merge
```

You could of-course filter this by appending desired branch name or HEAD at the end of above command.

`git ls-remote git@github.com:<github username>/<git project name>.git <branch-name>`

OR

`git ls-remote git@github.com:<github username>/<git project name>.git HEAD`