# How do I add SSL to an NIO socket client?

Tags: java, ssl, nio

I have some code to connect to a remote server using the Java NIO libraries. I wrote the code to connect asynchronously with callbacks, and it works great when the host is just a regular TCP server. But when the server uses SSL, it appears that I have to make a bunch of modifications. What I want to do is set up SSL only to the point where it checks to see if the server certificate is valid, i.e. issued by a certificate authority and not expired. I do not want to do anything more extensive than that (like name checking). In other words I just want very basic SSL behavior. Also, I plan to run this on Android, so I really can't do a whole lot of fumbling with external keystores and all that on the client side. I want to do everything I have to internally to the app. If I can avoid any external cert files that would be great.

I'm stuck as to what exactly I need to do in order to proceed. I found some NIO socket setup code here as follows:

```
private void setupSecurity() {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secureRandom.nextInt();

    KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    clientKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream("client.jks"), "KeyStorePassword".toCharArray()); 

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(clientKeyStore);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(clientKeyStore, "KeyInKeystorePassword".toCharArray());

    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), secureRandom);
}
```

And after this, there is a bunch of apparently horrendous SSL handshke code that must be implemented manually. The problem with the above code is that I have no idea what I am supposed to have inside the client.jks file. I don't want to have to have some sort of keystore file to begin with.

I found a library called Naga that claims to implement SSL sockets, but it doesn't work on an SSL socket server I have set up - I get an exception:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: BTW I found the above code here: http://www.lusta.hu/2011/07/25/securing-nio-java-ssl-tutorial/

Comment: This code is just for initialising the `SSLContext`, which is independent of using NIO/BIO, and which you might not even need to do. In addition, it doesn't necessarily make sense to use the clientKeyStore for the trustmanager. It's also better to use `TrustManager.getDefaultAlgorithm()` instead of "SunX509" in the TMF (since the default is PKIX, not SunX509).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `SSLEngine,` which is no joke in itself, and I'm not sure it works correctly on Android, although I am open to correction. The `SSLEngine` is a state machine and takes a lot of implementing. Frankly having done it I would forget it and use `SSLSockets.`

Answer (score -4):

This was actually discussed before here: [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java).

I ended up using [Java Secure Channel (JSCH)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which is documented here: [JSCH javadoc](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/)

Comment: What does SSH have to do with SSL?

Comment: To be more precise than @Bruno (for once), (a) it wasn't 'discussed before here', and (b) SSH is not SSL. -1.