# How to telnet using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, telnet

Is it possible to telnet/ssh using Selenium WebDriver?
Note: Writing test scripts in Java Code.

Thanks,
Hanuman.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: Connect to a linux box using PuTTY (Telnet/SSH).
Once connect to PuTTY, need to scan barcodes of retail items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium webdriver isn't designed to enable remote execution of commands with telnet or ssh

If you wish to do this then are are other third party libraries apart from selenium that can help you do this, the ssh ones are discussed in this answer [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)