# Run linux command in remote machine from java

Tags: java, linux, bash, ssh, remote-access

I´m working with application in java.
I can execute linux command (bash) on my machine host, but i want to execute this command in a remote machine like ssh. 
I´m ussing this code

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println(line);
    }
```

How i can execute linux shell in remote machine with java code?

Comment: Have you looked at an `ssh` library for Java like the one in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/996415/4687135.  Also, perhaps your script can do the ssh part for you?

Comment: This code it's running in a windows machine and i need execute bash script in a Linux remote machine. I'll try that library Thank you!!

Comment: someone knows a method for remote connection? I can't connect yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis: as Eric suggested one possible solution is to run a local script that performs an SSH itself on the remote server.

For instance if you have a Linux->Linux environment, your script you could have something like:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotehost 'bash -s' < localscripttoexecuteremotely.sh
```

In a Windows->Linux scenario you could do:

```
plink remoteuser@remotehost -m localscripttoexecuteremotely.sh
```

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) for additional information.

Comment: That´s right Execute a remote script it's the best way