# Java SSH Server Library

Tags: java, ssh

I would like to choose a good **'SSH Server' library in Java** for my project.

I know that there are bunch of libraries available out there like,

- Apache-Mina
- SSHJ
- JSch (some improved versions too)
- Ganymed

AFAIK, apache mina alone helps us in creating the server part, whereas others provide us only the ssh client.

My question is, I would like to create a full-fledged server part which would authenticate, accept ssh session etc., in my project. Please provide your suggestions on choosing the right library.

**Note:** I presume this question could have been asked earlier, but still I would like to know the best current/updated libraries, and moreover specific to the server part.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in that session ? Perhaps crash (http://www.crashub.org/) is better ?

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: @Marged Yes, this question has been asked earlier. But none of them talks about library for developing SSH Server (sshd). Between, I will look into crashub :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which functions you want to provide on the server side you might take a different approach.

If you want to provide Java code that can be accessed using a SSH / command line syntax, [CraSH](http://www.crashub.org/) could be a solution to your demands.