# Java SSH Client (running commands and catching answers) Remote Device

Tags: java, ssh, client, remote-access

I want to implement application working on Internet (I have remote Devices connected using Internet), I want to develop Java application to perform changes on remote devices....

I found this link example/code (http://twit88.com/blog/2007/12/22/java-writing-an-automated-telnet-client/) working in Telnet but is insecure I want to use SSH.

JSCH can help me (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)? or have you another alternative.

If you have similar code....

Thank you

Comment: Related answer at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java"

Comment: This is pretty vague. What is your actual question? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**JSch** is be the best solution.

You can use my code snippet as an example:
https://gist.github.com/kobylinsky/1c2b21c73b68a0daa91f