# How to run Mysql queries in Jmeter after ssh into amazon instance

Tags: mysql, ssh, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am able to SSH into amazon instance using **SSH Sampler plugin** after SSH'ing into instance **I want to run Mysql queries to edit database entries.**

I'm able to run commands like cd, ls after SSH'ing but unable to run Mysql queries.

Mysql queries work fine on running it on terminal.

Here is the **snapshot of SSH Sampler plugin**:

[image]

Comment: There are better alternative solutions to run mysql queries in amazon instance. Can you please share requirements so I can suggest a solution that does not involve ssh sampler but still do the job!

Comment: You appear to want a terminal style virtual user.  Have you considered leveraging any number of SSH libraries for Java?  See thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: Yes, i was looking for terminal style virtual user where i can ssh into instance and run some api's as well as edit database entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** use [mysql execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) like:

```
mysql -u root -pROOT_PASSWORD -e "YOUR_QUERY_HERE"
```

Example:

```
mysql -u root -psecret -e "use mysql; select name, url from help_topic limit 5;"
```

[image: MySQL Command Execution Demo]

**Option 2:** use [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) Sampler.

Given you have:

- [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) library in JMeter classpath
- Have port 3306 (or whatever) open in firewall and [Amazon Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

You should be able to run arbitrary queries using JDBC Request Sampler, if you need to load test MySQL instance - it will be the best way to proceed.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks you, this helps a lot. I was looking for the exact solution.