# Java Create a folder using ip address

Tags: java

I need to create a folder on my remote machine. For testing purpose, I am trying to create folder on my own machine using my machine IP address. My Ubuntu machine IP address is XX.X.X.XX. I want to create a folder called E book on my home directory using the following java code snippet. But the following doesn't create a folder. Please help.

```
boolean folder = new java.io.File("//XX.X.X.XX/home/EBook").mkdirs();
```

System.out.println(folder);

Comment: I think it is not that easy, you should check how to do it by SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by executing a process in java:

```
BufferedReader stdError = null;
try
{
    // change the you and server accordingly
    String command = "ssh you@server \"mkdir /home/name/EBook\"";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if (stdError != null)
    {
        try
        {
            stdError.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response. I did change the "you" to root and "server" to my ip address but it does not create the folder. It does not show any error and does not do anything.

Comment: Try to run the ssh command outside of java first. Example, just try `ssh root@server` to see if you can access it. You may have to do some setup first to allow ssh from your machine to the remote server. I will also add to my post how to read any errors produced by running the command.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis - you assumed he got ssh command installed locally which may not be.

Comment: @Tenzin, what is the purpose of creating folders on remote machine? Maybe there are alternatives if you can explain what you try to achive?

Comment: @Michael I did install ssh and ran your code with the correct ip address and     path. I am trying to create cat folder. It shows below.  run:
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

bash: mkdir /home/name/cat: No such file or directory
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: @Minh the purpose is the server to create a folder for each remote machine where the client at the remote machine adds its own files in the respective folder.

Comment: @Tenzin, sounds like you want to use SSH to login and create folders on remote Linux machine. Try using a proper library which will give proper response if anything went wrong. Have a look at this post and see if that help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java