# ssh configuration using java to connect multiple machines

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, ssh

Using putty able to do an ssh from one machine to another machine and from there another so on.Like a chain process.I want to do the same with java program. so far I am able to connect one machine and able to run scripts.From that machine how to do ssh configuration to connect the subsequent machines.Also I want to execute some commands. using java

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: tried with the same libraries it is working to connect one machine. i want to ssh from machine 1 to 2 then from 2 to 3 and also execute some basic commands in any of the machine